# Adding element class if background color is blue

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to javascript and I am working on a page and trying to get a class added to an element based on the element's background color, if it is set to `rgb(32, 44, 62)` I want to add a class to the element. As it is coded now it adds it to all matching elements not just the ones with the background color. Below is my test of the code. Any insights would be extremely helpful.

https://codepen.io/tyearyean/pen/PoWvLwO

```
var basicBGColor = $('section.content_basic').css('background-color');
```

Javascript

```
    var basicBGColor = $('section.content_basic').css('background-color');

    $('section.content_basic').each(function() {
      if (basicBGColor == 'rgb(32, 44, 62)') {
        $(this).addClass('goldBorder');
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put
`var basicBGColor = $('section.content_basic').css('background-color');` inside the each loop.

Because, if u declare this variable outside of the loop.It will only be executed once and always will be true, hence making this condition `if (basicBGColor == 'rgb(32, 44, 62)')`  always true and  therefore would add the same class for all the elements in the each loop.

Your updated code would look like this:

```
 

    $('section.content_basic').each(function() {
      let basicBGColor = $(this).css('background-color');
      if (basicBGColor == 'rgb(32, 44, 62)') {
        $(this).addClass('goldBorder');
      };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to Javascript too but I do believe that if you want to check equivalence you should use (===) not (==).

So instead of this:

```
(basicBGColor == 'rgb(32, 44, 62)')
```

Try using this:

```
(basicBGColor === 'rgb(32, 44, 62)')
```

Comment: That's not entirely wrong, but not entirely true neither and it won't solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

> As it is coded now it adds it to all matching elements not just the
> ones with the background color.

If you want to check individual element, you should get exactly the element's `background-color` like below:

```js
$('section.content_basic').each(function() {
  const basicBGColor = $(this).css('background-color');
  const isMatching = basicBGColor == 'rgb(32, 44, 62)'; 
  isMatching && $(this).addClass('goldBorder');
});
```

```css
.content_basic {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%,auto;
    position:relative;
}
.goldBorder:after{
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #a48147;
    z-index: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.goldBorder .body-content {padding: 2.5rem;color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="main-content" class="">
  <section style="background-color: rgb(32, 44, 62);" uk-scrollspy="cls:uk-animation-slide-bottom-small;offset-top:50;delay:200" class="content_basic">
    <article style="padding:5% 0;" class="uk-padding-large uk-padding-remove-left uk-container uk-padding-remove-right interior">
                                <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-stack" uk-grid="">
                                                                                                    <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-width-1-1@m uk-first-column">
                            <div class="uk-light body-content">
                                
                                <h2 style="color: rgb(164, 129, 71);">Title</h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis posuere leo eu sem mollis, et porta leo pretium. Morbi placerat placerat auctor. Vestibulum egestas nisl eget efficitur dictum. Cras commodo arcu libero, at scelerisque nulla semper ut. Praesent sed massa finibus nisi posuere ultrices. Cras imperdiet imperdiet enim, vel fringilla nunc ultricies non. Aliquam laoreet cursus urna id fermentum. Nullam magna nisl, sodales vel semper sed, lobortis vel ante. Proin volutpat at neque a maximus. Mauris sit amet rutrum nulla. Sed vel eros ut lacus interdum mollis et ut eros.</p>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>     
         
    </article>
</section>

<section style="" uk-scrollspy="cls:uk-animation-slide-bottom-small;offset-top:50;delay:200" class="content_basic">
    <article style="padding:5% 0;" class="uk-padding-large uk-padding-remove-left uk-container uk-padding-remove-right interior">
                                <div class="uk-grid uk-grid-stack" uk-grid="">
                                                                                                    <div class="uk-flex uk-flex-center uk-width-1-1@m uk-first-column">
                            <div class=" body-content">
                                
                                <h2 style="text-align: center;">Title</h2>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                                </div>     
         
    </article>
</section>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this code out and see if works.